# Are Playthrough 2.5 enemies different from Playthrough 2 at levels 50+?

Tags: borderlands-2

It was answered elsewhere that items are independent of the playthrough they dropped on - a level 50 shotgun is still the same level 50 shotgun.

Does it stand for enemies, though? Is a level 51 Architect the same as level 51... whatever are Engineers called in PT2.5?

Comment: Enemy levels _aren't_ capped. A PT2 level 50 architect may become a level 51 or 52 architect.

Comment: @badp they're capped at player level +/- 3 I believe. Badasses and bosses can be 53, most will be arounbd 48-52

Comment: @BenBrocka That means level 51 and 52 are definitely up for grabs in PT2½.

Comment: @badp not sure how that's relevant though, an enemy of X level is still X level, and loot drops are still capped at level 50

Comment: @BenBrocka I thought level cap for enemies was an implicit assumption in the question. That's about it.

Comment: @badp question seemed to be "is a level 50 playthrough 2 X enemy the same as a level 50 playthrough 2.5 X enemy", not anything about the level itself. After all there are differences between playthrough 1 mob behavior and playthrough 2 behavior (Goliath Blasters, juggernaughts etc)

Comment: @badp Yes, I meant differences between enemies of the same level. Actually, in the end of PT2, even some rakk are 51... Editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no new enemy types on Playthrough 2.5, unlike playthrough 2.0 which introduces things like Armored Psychos or Bullyrots. I think (but am not sure) certain enemies change names (pyro pete the invincible -> pyro pete the ultra invincible) but I've noticed nothing different about enemies whatsoever in Playthrough 2.5 besides the fact that their levels are higher (and the resulting difficulty increase).

If enemies do change names, it's certainly not as noticable in BL1's playthrough 2.0. For instance Baddass enemies are still  Badass or Super Badass, no more Bad Mutha Skags etc.

Comment: "Bad Mutha" is what I miss most about BL1 :(

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk I actually prefer Badass, it was a defining part of Borderlands' terminology. It's like seeing Psychos called...anything not-Psycho, it feels wrong. Now my Double Anarchy, *that* I miss more than anything...

Comment: Yeaa I agree with Psycho being better than like Maniac for instance. It should go Maniac then Psycho if anything

Comment: @BenBrocka On the other hand, there was an exception from SuperBad... Asskicking Skags, now that's a part of Borderlands! :-)